# Could omission of "^" when accessing a record pointer's members cause an access violation?

Tags: delphi, pointers, access-violation, dereference

In VirtualTreeview, I am storing my data in the **PVirtualNodes**. I have experienced several Access Violations (typically with *"Read of adress 00000000"*) in my App, and they mostly (I'd actually dare to say Always) occur when I am doing something with my Node Data.

However, the thing is, I declare my stuff & use it like this:

```
// DUMMY CODE - Not written or tested in IDE
var
 MyNode : PVirtualNode;
 MyData : PMyNodeData;
Begin
 MyNode := VST.GetFirstSelected;

 if Assigned(MyNode) then
  Begin
   MyData := VST.GetNodeData(MyNode);
   if Assigned(MyData) then
   Begin
     MyData.DummyProperty := 'Test';
   End;
  End;
End;
```

As you probably noticed, I do not *"dereference"* (correct?) my **"MyData"** by doing **MyData^**! The reason I don't is that I have been told it was not necessary to add the caret to the pointer name, however I have a feeling that it has something to do with it. If I knew, I wouldn't be posting on here. ;)

So my question is: Is it in the end necessary to add the little `^` to MyData? And is it possible that by not doing that, I may provoke an Access Violation?

Comment: @Marjan - The thing is, I can't really provoke one, they just happen from time to time.

Comment: @Jeff: that bit of information is quite crucial. It still doesn't tell me whether you did or did not try some basic experimentation yourself (before asking the question), it does tell me (and everybody else) that your problem is definitely somewhere else and it "only" manifests itself here. The problem most likely is that you are, unintentionally, overwriting memory somewhere and sometimes that "just happens" to be the location where MyData points - ie the node data of your virtual treeview gets corrupted... Not much more I can tell you about that I'm afraid...

Comment: @Marjan - as soon as I have dug my way to the other side of the Good Stuff (the info I am able to provide about this error) I will post another question. This question was solely about whether or not the ^ was required :)

Comment: .. It's actually gonna be kinda hard, since I dont expect that any of you know anything about the Skype API, which might also be a suspect.

Comment: The Skype API may be causing access violations but you should always treat your own code as the primary suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a pointer to a record, then you can omit the ^.  The following are equivalent:

```
MyData.DummyProperty
MyData^.DummyProperty
```

This is also the case for the deprecated Turbo Pascal `object`. I would expect it to be so for Delphi classes, although I have never tried with them since they are already reference types.

Sadly, this is not the explanation for your AV.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is part of the so called extended syntax, which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Using ^ to dereference records is optionnal as it is assumed implicitly by the compiler.  When not using any hard typecast, any situation that would requires the "^" would not compile. But only 1 level of dereferencing is implicit.

```
type
  TMyRecord  = record
    MyField : Integer;
  end;
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
  PPMyRecord = ^PMyRecord;

procedure DoSomething;
var vMyField : PPMyRecord;
begin
  vMyField.MyField;  <---Won't compile
  vMyField^.MyField; <---Will compile
end;
```

As for your access violation, here's my best guess based on what you wrote... Assuming your exemple is representative (i.e. that is, crash on assigning a string), and assuming PMyNodeData points to a record.  I'd guess that PMyNodeData's memory was reserved with "GetMem" instead of "New", making the string field of the record uninitialized.

Comment: I am not using GetMem, or New actually. I will post another Q once I have more info (that is, I have an idea of where to start). :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an exception where `Data.xx` and `Data^.xx` are not the same: when the field pointed at is of the same pointer type or the generic pointer type:

```
var
  x: PPointer;
  y: Pointer;
begin
  x := GetPPointer();
  y := x;
  y := x^;
end;
```

I consider it best practice to always add the operator `^` when the pointed value is used to avoid ambiguous situations like above.

Given your example: The problem is possibly memory corruption. Did you set `NodeDataSize` correctly?

Comment: I don't understand this example. Where is the `.` member access operator used?

Comment: Yes, I have the NodeDataSize set in the OnGetNodeDataSize event (or whatever its called)